# How to provision httpd.conf for SSL configuration if I want to visit by https?

Tags: gnu, alm

I have just configured my server with an open-source ALM tool, e.g. ZenTao. Now I need to edit httpd.conf to visit it through my domain with https, but I don't know-how, could someone help with that?
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNU) and I have already applied for a certificate for my domain from Letsencrypt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your https work for your ZenTao domain, you should provision your httpd.conf with port 443 details, which you could refer to the following,

DocumentRoot and Directory should be your /zentao/www root,
And you should configure with your SSL certificates in it as well,

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName *.xxx.com
  ServerAlias *.xxx.com
  DocumentRoot "/zentaoalm/www/"

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile     /etc/apache2/ssl/xxx.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/xxx.com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxx.com.pem

  <Directory "/zentaopms/www">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```